# Entity Framework Code First n-tier example (not ASP)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am new to Entity Framework but have spend a lot of time reading through the snippets of the code, Julie Lerman book, Scott Gu's blog...

I think I have come to understand a lot, but now am at a point when all needs to be tied together in quite complex layered project.

Since I have no background in developing for the web, and all examples that I could find are either simple console applications or are using ASP & MVC I have the hard time understanding the (ASP) examples posted - what is applicable in developing desktop application using WPF and MVVM?

In short, is there any layered example that is not simple console application or ASP.NET, that has CRUD elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

[Microsoft Spain - Domain Oriented N-Layered .NET 4.0 Sample App](http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks promising.